Simplest way to backup entire Android device offline without using cloud
I have multiple Samsung android stock handsets (not rooted) and I need to backup the data to my Linux pc.
Call logs, SMS, Photos, WhatsApp Messages, Samsung notes, Spotify, etc.
One problem I've found is that data like call logs and SMS do not appear to exist as files on the device, or if they do are hidden away in directory paths that may not be accessible depending on Android version - Eg Android 10 we can view Internal Storage/Android/data, but in Android 11 we cannot.
Additionally, data like WhatsApp messages would require the manual exporting of each and every chat thread, this is a very tiresome and exhaustive process.
Ideally I'm seeking a method akin to Linux
dd if=handset of=pc

This way the entire device is backed up in one go, and if I need to access a specific file, I can do so later, without the dread of potentially forgetting to save x file from x path
What is the simplest way I can wholesomely, in a timely manner, save the data from these devices and continue with my life?
Somebody has mentioned using EDL, but another said EDL only works if you want to restore the backup to that Exact device, whereas I want to save files to my pc.

Using dd requires root permissions. And the user data partition will be encrypted and the key is not included in the dd backup as it is located in the TEE or HSM module. Therefore if you have root access tar-ing all file on the user data partition is usually a better approach as the files will be decrypted that way.

@Robert Thanks for the suggestion, the problem is in order to get root, ive got to wipe device, so I guess its out of the question.
For future, do you know any phone OS thats simpler, I dont want to use Android anymore after this headache... its insane how over complicated it is to backup parts of the device.
